# How can we convert .ipynb file to json?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Is it possible to load one **.ipynb** file to a json? I have file **data.ipynb** and I want to load and save it as a **json** to my notebook. I have following code to load data but it does not work.

```
import json 

with open("data.ipynb", mode= "r", encoding= "utf-8") as f:
    myfile = json.load(f)
myfile
```

Comment: "I have the following code to load data but it does not work" -- You should specify exactly what isn't working.  Do you get an error message?  If so, you should edit it into your post.  Does it hang?  Does it just give you back an empty string?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
myfile = json.load(f)
```

to

```
myfile = json.loads(f.read())
```

f is an object of file. You want the content of the file.

Comment: but this gives me following error ." AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'"

Comment: @Daniel then what you're doing isn't what you posted, f shouldn't be a str object

Comment: @Daniel -- As alluded to by abccd, you haven't shown us your _actual_ code.  If you want to load json from a `str` then you should use `json.loads`.

Comment: I did actually use ``loads`` when testing this. Updated the answer.

Comment: Yeah you definitely need ``loads`` not ``load`` sorry for the typo.

Comment: @Visgean Skeloru , Thank you for your comments. I changed it to loads, this time I get this error "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)".  just to mention once more my original file is .ipynb and it has some notes, markedown and code.

Comment: Well your file is then not a valid ipynb. Anyway. Why do you exactly want to do this? It might be preferable for you to use some kind of wrapper that jupyter has built in.

Comment: I used used to use `json` to load ipynb (same as @VisgeanSkeloru's answer). But now I started getting this error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 34366: ordinal not in range(128)`. It might be because I updated my jupyter version recently, but I am not sure if that's the reason.